# How to install downloaded devtoolset-6 rpms?

Tags: rpm, rhel6, devtoolset

```
 6158304 Jun  1 01:55 devtoolset-6-binutils-2.27-10.el6.1.x86_64.rpm
  906716 Jun  1 01:55 devtoolset-6-binutils-devel-2.27-10.el6.1.i686.rpm
  852324 Jun  1 01:55 devtoolset-6-binutils-devel-2.27-10.el6.1.x86_64.rpm
    4836 Mar  1 09:11 devtoolset-6-build-6.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
   99048 Oct 12  2016 devtoolset-6-dwz-0.12-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
 3594180 Oct  3  2016 devtoolset-6-dyninst-9.2.0-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
  245324 Oct  3  2016 devtoolset-6-dyninst-devel-9.2.0-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
 4274876 Oct  3  2016 devtoolset-6-dyninst-doc-9.2.0-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
 4425152 Oct  3  2016 devtoolset-6-dyninst-static-9.2.0-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
36715348 Oct  3  2016 devtoolset-6-dyninst-testsuite-9.2.0-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
  365020 Mar  1 09:09 devtoolset-6-elfutils-0.168-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
 1235124 Mar  1 09:09 devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.i686.rpm
 1250360 Mar  1 09:09 devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
  193644 Mar  1 09:09 devtoolset-6-elfutils-libelf-0.168-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
  336468 Mar  1 09:09 devtoolset-6-elfutils-libelf-devel-0.168-3.el6.i686.rpm
  343420 Mar  1 09:09 devtoolset-6-elfutils-libelf-devel-0.168-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
  265532 Mar  1 09:09 devtoolset-6-elfutils-libs-0.168-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
30883432 Feb 25 12:59 devtoolset-6-gcc-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
11209592 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-gcc-c++-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
   84720 Feb 25 12:59 devtoolset-6-gcc-gdb-plugin-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
11145268 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-gcc-gfortran-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
 1374232 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-gcc-plugin-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
 3046896 Mar 13 05:11 devtoolset-6-gdb-7.12.1-47.el6.x86_64.rpm
 3866836 Mar 13 05:11 devtoolset-6-gdb-doc-7.12.1-47.el6.noarch.rpm
  349420 Mar 13 05:11 devtoolset-6-gdb-gdbserver-7.12.1-47.el6.x86_64.rpm
  412948 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libasan-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686.rpm
  416412 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libasan-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
   17772 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libatomic-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686.rpm
   18392 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libatomic-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
   56952 Feb 25 12:59 devtoolset-6-libcilkrts-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686.rpm
   57360 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libcilkrts-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
 6615180 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686.rpm
 6651560 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
   22760 Feb 25 12:59 devtoolset-6-libgccjit-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686.rpm
   22744 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libgccjit-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
  447176 Feb 25 12:59 devtoolset-6-libgccjit-docs-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
   54844 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libitm-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686.rpm
   54176 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libitm-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
  179820 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-liblsan-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
   18176 Feb 25 12:59 devtoolset-6-libmpx-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686.rpm
   17684 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libmpx-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
  218192 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libquadmath-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686.rpm
  158852 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libquadmath-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
 2866372 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libstdc++-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686.rpm
 2737076 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libstdc++-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
12907388 Feb 25 12:59 devtoolset-6-libstdc++-docs-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
  352696 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libtsan-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
  176832 Feb 25 12:58 devtoolset-6-libubsan-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686.rpm
  167248 Feb 25 12:59 devtoolset-6-libubsan-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
  136568 Mar  9 06:48 devtoolset-6-ltrace-0.7.91-13.el6.x86_64.rpm
  469192 Sep 26  2016 devtoolset-6-make-4.1-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
  377404 Oct 14  2016 devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686.rpm
  348964 Oct 14  2016 devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.x86_64.rpm
 2785304 Oct 20  2016 devtoolset-6-oprofile-1.1.0-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
    6856 Oct 20  2016 devtoolset-6-oprofile-devel-1.1.0-4.el6.i686.rpm
    6820 Oct 20  2016 devtoolset-6-oprofile-devel-1.1.0-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
  359236 Oct 20  2016 devtoolset-6-oprofile-jit-1.1.0-4.el6.i686.rpm
  331068 Oct 20  2016 devtoolset-6-oprofile-jit-1.1.0-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
    4188 Mar  1 09:11 devtoolset-6-perftools-6.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
 1092752 Mar  1 09:11 devtoolset-6-runtime-6.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
  432012 Oct 12  2016 devtoolset-6-strace-4.12-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
  146888 Oct 14  2016 devtoolset-6-systemtap-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64.rpm
 2026788 Oct 14  2016 devtoolset-6-systemtap-client-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64.rpm
 2095124 Oct 14  2016 devtoolset-6-systemtap-devel-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64.rpm
   28340 Oct 14  2016 devtoolset-6-systemtap-initscript-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64.rpm
  400008 Oct 14  2016 devtoolset-6-systemtap-runtime-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64.rpm
  202468 Oct 14  2016 devtoolset-6-systemtap-sdt-devel-3.0-8s.el6.i686.rpm
  202428 Oct 14  2016 devtoolset-6-systemtap-sdt-devel-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64.rpm
  362864 Oct 14  2016 devtoolset-6-systemtap-server-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64.rpm
 1030832 Oct 14  2016 devtoolset-6-systemtap-testsuite-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64.rpm
    4384 Mar  1 09:11 devtoolset-6-toolchain-6.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
 9034988 Nov  1  2016 devtoolset-6-valgrind-3.12.0-1.el6.i686.rpm
 9976088 Nov  1  2016 devtoolset-6-valgrind-3.12.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
 2171604 Nov  1  2016 devtoolset-6-valgrind-devel-3.12.0-1.el6.i686.rpm
 2135396 Nov  1  2016 devtoolset-6-valgrind-devel-3.12.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

I downloaded above devtoolset-6 rpm packages,
But when i am trying to install all packages it shows like this:-

```
 [root@ip-xx.xx.xx.xx rpm_pack]# rpm -ivh devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.i686.rpm
    error: Failed dependencies:
    bzip2-devel is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.i686
    devtoolset-6-elfutils-libelf-devel(x86-32) = 0.168-3.el6 is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.i686
    pkgconfig(libelf) = 0.168 is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.i686
    pkgconfig(liblzma) is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.i686
    pkgconfig(zlib) is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.i686
    xz-devel is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.i686
    zlib-devel >= 1.2.2.3 is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.i686
```

I know these are correct but it depends on each other,
Is there any way to find out which rpm supposed install first??

I am insatlling offline mode (physically copies these rpm files into RHEL server 6.4)

when i install all packages using this command

```
      rpm -ivh *.rpm
```

It shows error like this

```
      error: Failed dependencies:
    zlib-devel is needed by devtoolset-6-binutils-devel-2.27-10.el6.1.i686
    zlib-devel is needed by devtoolset-6-binutils-devel-2.27-10.el6.1.x86_64
    scl-utils-build >= 20120927-11 is needed by devtoolset-6-build-6.1-1.el6.x86_64
    libboost_system-mt.so.5()(64bit) is needed by devtoolset-6-dyninst-9.2.0-4.el6.x86_64
    libboost_thread-mt.so.5()(64bit) is needed by devtoolset-6-dyninst-9.2.0-4.el6.x86_64
    boost-devel is needed by devtoolset-6-dyninst-devel-9.2.0-4.el6.x86_64
    glibc-static is needed by devtoolset-6-dyninst-testsuite-9.2.0-4.el6.x86_64
    bzip2-devel is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.i686
    pkgconfig(liblzma) is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.i686
    pkgconfig(zlib) is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.i686
    xz-devel is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.i686
    zlib-devel >= 1.2.2.3 is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.i686
    bzip2-devel is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.x86_64
    pkgconfig(liblzma) is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.x86_64
    pkgconfig(zlib) is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.x86_64
    xz-devel is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.x86_64
    zlib-devel >= 1.2.2.3 is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-devel-0.168-3.el6.x86_64
    pkgconfig(zlib) is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-libelf-devel-0.168-3.el6.i686
    pkgconfig(zlib) is needed by devtoolset-6-elfutils-libelf-devel-0.168-3.el6.x86_64
    glibc-devel >= 2.2.90-12 is needed by devtoolset-6-gcc-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
    libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) is needed by devtoolset-6-gcc-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
    libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) is needed by devtoolset-6-gcc-c++-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
    libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) is needed by devtoolset-6-gcc-gfortran-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
    gmp-devel >= 4.1.2-8 is needed by devtoolset-6-gcc-plugin-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
    mpfr-devel >= 2.2.1 is needed by devtoolset-6-gcc-plugin-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
    libasan3 >= 5.1.1 is needed by devtoolset-6-libasan-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libasan3 >= 5.1.1 is needed by devtoolset-6-libasan-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
    libatomic >= 4.8.0 is needed by devtoolset-6-libatomic-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libatomic >= 4.8.0 is needed by devtoolset-6-libatomic-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
    libcilkrts >= 5.1.1 is needed by devtoolset-6-libcilkrts-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libcilkrts >= 5.1.1 is needed by devtoolset-6-libcilkrts-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
    ld-linux.so.2 is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    ld-linux.so.2(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6 is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11) is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.3) is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.4) is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2) is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libdl.so.2 is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libgmp.so.3 is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libm.so.6 is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libmpfr.so.1 is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libz.so.1 is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libmpfr.so.1()(64bit) is needed by devtoolset-6-libgccjit-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
    liblsan >= 5.1.1 is needed by devtoolset-6-liblsan-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
    libmpx >= 5.1.1 is needed by devtoolset-6-libmpx-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libmpx >= 5.1.1 is needed by devtoolset-6-libmpx-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
    libstdc++(x86-32) is needed by devtoolset-6-libstdc++-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libtsan >= 5.1.1 is needed by devtoolset-6-libtsan-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
    libubsan >= 5.1.1 is needed by devtoolset-6-libubsan-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.i686
    libubsan >= 5.1.1 is needed by devtoolset-6-libubsan-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
    libc.so.6 is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.3) is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.4) is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7) is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.8) is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    libdl.so.2 is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    libpthread.so.0 is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    librt.so.1 is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    libz.so.1 is needed by devtoolset-6-memstomp-0.1.5-5.el6.i686
    libc.so.6 is needed by devtoolset-6-oprofile-jit-1.1.0-4.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by devtoolset-6-oprofile-jit-1.1.0-4.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by devtoolset-6-oprofile-jit-1.1.0-4.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by devtoolset-6-oprofile-jit-1.1.0-4.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by devtoolset-6-oprofile-jit-1.1.0-4.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.3) is needed by devtoolset-6-oprofile-jit-1.1.0-4.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) is needed by devtoolset-6-oprofile-jit-1.1.0-4.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by devtoolset-6-oprofile-jit-1.1.0-4.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7) is needed by devtoolset-6-oprofile-jit-1.1.0-4.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.8) is needed by devtoolset-6-oprofile-jit-1.1.0-4.el6.i686
    libdl.so.2 is needed by devtoolset-6-oprofile-jit-1.1.0-4.el6.i686
    libz.so.1 is needed by devtoolset-6-oprofile-jit-1.1.0-4.el6.i686
    scl-utils >= 20120927-11 is needed by devtoolset-6-runtime-6.1-1.el6.x86_64
    kernel-devel is needed by devtoolset-6-systemtap-devel-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64
    libjson-c.so.2()(64bit) is needed by devtoolset-6-systemtap-runtime-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64
    /usr/bin/expect is needed by devtoolset-6-systemtap-testsuite-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64
    /usr/bin/nc is needed by devtoolset-6-systemtap-testsuite-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64
    /usr/bin/stap is needed by devtoolset-6-systemtap-testsuite-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64
    /usr/bin/tclsh is needed by devtoolset-6-systemtap-testsuite-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64
    /usr/lib/libc.so is needed by devtoolset-6-systemtap-testsuite-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64
    avahi is needed by devtoolset-6-systemtap-testsuite-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64
    dejagnu is needed by devtoolset-6-systemtap-testsuite-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64
    gcc-c++ is needed by devtoolset-6-systemtap-testsuite-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64
    glibc-devel is needed by devtoolset-6-systemtap-testsuite-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64
    nc is needed by devtoolset-6-systemtap-testsuite-3.0-8s.el6.x86_64
    libc.so.6 is needed by devtoolset-6-valgrind-1:3.12.0-1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by devtoolset-6-valgrind-1:3.12.0-1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by devtoolset-6-valgrind-1:3.12.0-1.el6.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by devtoolset-6-valgrind-1:3.12.0-1.el6.i686
    libdl.so.2 is needed by devtoolset-6-valgrind-1:3.12.0-1.el6.i686
    libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by devtoolset-6-valgrind-1:3.12.0-1.el6.i686
    libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.3.3) is needed by devtoolset-6-valgrind-1:3.12.0-1.el6.i686
    libpthread.so.0 is needed by devtoolset-6-valgrind-1:3.12.0-1.el6.i686
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by devtoolset-6-valgrind-1:3.12.0-1.el6.i686
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by devtoolset-6-valgrind-1:3.12.0-1.el6.i686
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.3) is needed by devtoolset-6-valgrind-1:3.12.0-1.el6.i686
```

What i supposed to do, help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way is using something like `repotrack` to try to get all the dependencies. Another option is to configure a VM that is internet connected with the same packages as the airgapped one, do a `yum` install from there, and then pull the required packages from yum's cache.

Comment: can you tell me the full **repotrack ** command with their options, I am struggling since last two days help me, please..

Comment: How to pull the required packages from yum's cache, tell me the step-by-step process...

Comment: I don't use `repotrack`, sorry, I just saw it mentioned in other questions that said "how do I download an RPM and its dependencies." The `yum` cache is in `/var/cache/yum/<reponame>/packages/` I believe.